# Grunt 0.4 less task : How to not concatenate destination files

Tags: less, gruntjs

I want to generate .css partial files from the corresponding .less files

I use the latest versions available from npm, grunt@0.4.0, grunt-contrib-less@0.5.0

Prior to Grunt version 0.4 I could simply specify the pattern:

`htdocs/less/*.less` as source

`htdocs/css/*.css` as destination

and all the files from the folder `htdocs/less` would be generated into the folder `htdocs/css`

Since v0.4 the destination pattern does no longer work, all files from the folder `htdocs/less` are concatenated into one file named `*.css`

How can I configure the task that it generates all files instead concatenating them into one file.

I do not want list the files individually.

Couldn't find an answer in the Grunt documentation http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files does

Thank You.

My Gruntfile.js (extract):

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            development: {
                files: {
                    "htdocs/css/*.css": "htdocs/less/*.less"
                }
            }
        },
    });
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'd want to read the [Building the files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) section in the docs.

This would be a direct translation from your current config:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            development: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,        // Enable dynamic expansion.
                    cwd: 'htdocs/less',  // Src matches are relative to this path.
                    src: ['*.less'],     // Actual pattern(s) to match.
                    dest: 'htdocs/css',  // Destination path prefix.
                    ext: '.css',         // Dest filepaths will have this extension.
                }]
            }
        },
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Sindre, exactly what I needed, I knew that page already, but I did not associate the title with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [assemble-less](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-less) as well. It's based on grunt-contrib-less but is specifically geared towards what you're looking to do. (full disclosure, I'm a maintainer of the project as well).

For this specific use-case, the advantage that [assemble-less](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-less) has over grunt-contrib-less is that it has a `concat: false` option that enables you to compiles LESS files individually using any of the src-dest patterns in Grunt. assemble-less also has a `require` option that will automatically prepend "global" less files (such as variables.less or mixins.less) onto all of the other specified less files, negating the need to actually add `@import` statements inside each less file.

So, for example, with [assemble-less](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-less) you would do:

```
  less: {
    development: {
      options: {
        concat: false
      }
      files: {
        "htdocs/css/": "htdocs/less/*.less"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: NOTE: the author has since removed this `concat` feature from `assemble-less`