# Compile to `.js` maintaining the same folder structure

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

In my app (Asp.net mvc) I have the following folder structure:

[image: Foder structure]

`Scripts` folder contains all `.js` and `.coffee` files. Inside the folder `Controllers` I have a folder for each controller.

I need that whenever a `.coffee` file changed, a new file `.js` is created in the same folder with the same name.

```
module.exports = (grunt) -> 
    # Configurações
    grunt.initConfig
        coffee:
            compile:
                options:
                    basePath: 'Scripts'
                    preserve_dirs: true
                files: 'Scripts/*.js': 'Scripts/**/*.coffee'

    # Plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-coffee'
```

**When I run grunt: `grunt coffee`** the following error occurs:

> Unable to write "Scripts/*.js" file (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue

[image: Erro grunt]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grunt 0.4 less task : How to not concatenate destination files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344584/grunt-0-4-less-task-how-to-not-concatenate-destination-files)

Comment: @SindreSorhus The answer may be the same, but the question is another.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use it that way:

```
coffee:
  compile:
    files: [
      expand: true
      cwd: "./Scripts"
      src: ["**/*.coffee"]
      dest: "./Scripts"
      ext: ".js"       
    ]
```

read more about it here: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically