# Grunt.js - uglify / yui compressor - one to one file mapping

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yui-compressor, minify, uglifyjs

I know I can uglify multiple files into one like this:

```
uglify: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'Scripts/build.js': ['Scripts/*.js']
        }
    }
}
```

But what if a want to uglify multiple files without bundling and without writing each file - one to one map.

Something like this:

```
uglify: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'Scripts/*.min.js': ['Scripts/*.js']
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible with either uglify or yui comressor?

Comment: did you find my answer useful?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grunt 0.4 less task : How to not concatenate destination files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344584/grunt-0-4-less-task-how-to-not-concatenate-destination-files)

Comment: @coma, yes that the one. thanks!

Comment: Why down-vote? even if its a similar question, for someone new to GRUNT it is not immediately obvious that less plugin works the same as uglify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      test: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: '*.js',
            dest: 'Scripts',
            cwd: 'Scripts',
            ext: '.min.js'
        }]
      }
    }
});
```