# Compile directories of coffee into the same directories of JS

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, coffeescript, gruntjs

How can I do this simple command: `coffee --bare --output js/ coffee/` 
in grunt-coffee config?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grunt 0.4 less task : How to not concatenate destination files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344584/grunt-0-4-less-task-how-to-not-concatenate-destination-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
{
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'coffee_dir',
  src: '**/*.coffee',
  dest: 'js_dir',
  ext: '.js'
}
```