# How to create multiple minified css files for multiple less files using grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-usemin

I have 5 less files. I want to convert this 5 less files into 5 diffrent css minified files using **grunt** .

```
https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-simple-guide-to-getting-started-with-grunt
```

By this tutorial I get to know that the converting multiple less files to single css file. But I want convert multiple to multiple

```
less: {
  build: {
    files: {
      'Aline-production/css/pretty.css': 'Aline-dev/css/*.less'
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way. Please any one can help me to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grunt 0.4 less task : How to not concatenate destination files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344584/grunt-0-4-less-task-how-to-not-concatenate-destination-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use grunt-sass but i imagine the following should work.

```
less: {
  build: {
    files: [
        {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'Aline-dev/css/',
            src: ['*.less'],
            dest: 'Aline-production/css/',
            ext: '.css'
        }
    ]
  }
}
```