# Grunt convert multiple less files to corresponding css files

Tags: gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

I have 2 less files **a.less** and **b.less**.
I want to convert them into **a.css** and **b.css** using grunt but grunt-contrib-less task concatinates the two files.

How can I convert both the less files into their corresponding css files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grunt 0.4 less task : How to not concatenate destination files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344584/grunt-0-4-less-task-how-to-not-concatenate-destination-files)